# Form vba filter for additional fields MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have this code for a filter option in my form. I want to built on the code to include multiple fields but I'm not sure if that is possible or how I could do that.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    If Not IsNull(Me.searchlat) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([Status] = """ & Me.searchlat & """) AND  "
    End If

    Me.Filter = strWhere
    Me.FilterOn = True
```

This is how I attempted to add additional fields and failed:

```
    strWhere = strWhere & "([Status] = """ & Me.searchlat & """) OR   [workername] = """ & Me.searchlat & """) AND "
```

Comment: Can you post the full code? I suspect that your if statement is in a loop. The current method puts the 'And' at the rear of the statement forcing you to find some method to remove it before running your filter.

Answer (score 2):

The number of brackets in your statement does not add up and the `AND` at the end is incorrect, because there is no further criteria linked by it.

Additionally I would recommend using single quotation marks inside the sql string. That makes clearer, which quotation mark has which purpose.

```
strWhere = strWhere & " [Status] = '" & Me.searchlat & "' OR [workername] = '" & Me.searchlat & "'"
```

The brackets had no effect in your excerpt at all therefore I removed them. But depending on the original where-condition in `strWhere` and the intention of your filter you might need to add some again.